# IPcop Multiple WAN Subnets

Tags: firewall, subnet, gateway, wide-area-network, ipcop

We have an IPcop firewall and have had no issues with it. We've had a block of 10 IP addresses from our colocation provider and have been able port forward from those to internal servers as needed. We've recently needed additional IPs and the colocation provider issued an additional block of 10.

The problem: The 10 new IP addresses issued are in a different subnet with a different gateway.

The question: How do I add the new gateway into IPcop? How do I make it so that any outbound traffic in response to any inbound traffic from a new IP go back out through the new gateway?

I attempted to add a static route via the console using the following command:

route add -net x.x.x.x gw x.x.x.x netmask 255.255.255.192

I also added the new IPs as aliases and setup port forwarding as I've done with the existing IP block. However, when I attempt to access a web server from an external workstation, it just times out.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.